Trying to write a userscript which redirects from a website which shows ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
I'm trying to have a script which redirects me from old burningseries domains to the newest ones, so I don't have to change all my bookmarks in chrome.
I tried the following code, which worked when pasted into the developer console but could not match the URL of the website.
// ==UserScript==
// @name           bs.to redirect
// @namespace      http://tampermonkey.net/
// @icon           https://bs.to/favicon.ico
// @version        1.0
// @description    Redirects burningseries to bs.to
// @author         
// @match          https://burningseries.co/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Get the current path and query parameters
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    var query = window.location.search;

    // Redirect to bs.to with the same path and query parameters
    window.location.href = "https://bs.to" + path + query;
})();


The error page is a built-in special page which cannot be scripted by extensions. You'll have to write an extension that detects the error using chrome.webNavigation API and redirects the tab. Such an extension may already exist.
